# Magento 2.3.1 - Deployed version mismatch

Tags: static-content, versioning

I'm trying to update my Magento 2.3.1 installation with some new files. However, it keeps referring to my OLD signed static file(s).

Inside pub/static/deployed_version.txt the number is updated, however, on the frontend it keeps referring to the old version that USED to be there.

What I've tried:

No result:

- `bin/magento cache:clean`
- `bin/magento cache:flush`
- `bin/magento index:reindex`

No result:

- empty directories `pub/static`, `var/view_preprocessed`, `generated`
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL`
- `bin/magento cache:clean`
- `bin/magento cache:flush`

I've tried to disable `Developer > Sign Static` and tried it with enable..no result.

If I check the directories, the files are created, but it keeps referring to the OLD version of static files.

This is on a production setting.

Comment: Have you check in private browser mode? after doing above things?

Comment: One of the first things I did.